# value not being updated after saga call react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I am using react-redux along with redux-saga. now I have problem that I have Modal which updates multiple value and click on save saga calls multiple times and reflects updated value on page. but on clicking of save it is not updating value on page.I need to make something to reload page i.e refresh but ideally my DOM should re render it,shouldn't it? here is my saga

```
import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { update } from '../services/api';
import * as types from '../constants/actionTypes';

export default function* updateSaga({ value }) {
    try {

        const updateData = yield value.map(data =>{ 

            return (call(update,data))}
    )

        yield [
            put({ type: types.UPDATES, updateData: updateData })

        ]
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("porfilingerror",error);
        yield put({
            type: 'FETCH_UPDATE_ERROR',
            error
        });
    }
}
```

Here's my reducer

```
case types.UPDATES:
       for(var i = 0;i<highestData.channel_mix.length;i++){
           for(var j= 0;j<action.updateData.length;j++){
               if(highestData.mix[i].pk === action.updateData[j].pk){
                   highestData.mix[i].volume = action.updateData[j].volume;
                   break;
               }
           }
       }

        dashboard_data[0].mix = highestData.mix;

        return {...state,
            highestProfiledata:highestData,
            program_data: dashboard_data

        }
```

EDIT 1:

here is my component code

```
console.log("rendering....")
return (
      <div id="otherProgram">
        <div className="panel panel-default">
          <div className="panel-heading panel-head">
            <h3 className="panel-title">OTHER DETAILS</h3>
            <Button
              onClick={() =>
                this.setState({
                  open: !this.state.open
                })}
            >
              <Glyphicon
                glyph={
                  this.state.open
                    ? 'glyphicon glyphicon-minus'
                    : 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus'
                }
              />
            </Button>
          </div>

          <Collapse in={this.state.open}>
            <Well>
              <div className="row other_pgm_data">
                <div className="col-md-4">
                  <h5> Mix</h5>
                  <div className="other_data_mix">
                    <table className="table table-bordered">
                      <thead>
                        <th />
                        <th>
                          {this.props.Data.year
                            .toString()
                            .substr(0, 4)}{' '}
                          mix
                        </th>
                        <th> Vol. growth </th>
                        <th> Volume </th>
                      </thead>

                      <tbody>
                        {this.props.profileData.mix.map(data =>
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                              {data.name}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                              {' '}{Math.round(data.volume * 100)}%{' '}
                            </td>
                            <td> {data.volume_growth}%</td>

                          </tr>
                        )}
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
```

Comment: If you are updating your state and there is any change in state AND you are referring that state in your DOM, the page will reflect the change for sure. Did you try to console.log inside your reducer or effect ?

Comment: ya it is passing value to props. and ya put logger to my component it didn't log after reducer reduces the value

Comment: So you mean the values are updated in state but not reflecting into your component? Can you also put your component code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are mutating a `highestData` instead of creating a new one

Not sure what structure you do have but atleast this should be rewritten

```
for(var i = 0;i<highestData.channel_mix.length;i++){
       for(var j= 0;j<action.updateData.length;j++){
           if(highestData.mix[i].pk === action.updateData[j].pk){
               highestData.mix[i].volume = action.updateData[j].volume;
               break;
           }
       }
   }
```

to something like this

```
highestData = {
  ...highestData ,
  mix: highestDat.mix.map(channel => {
     const update = action.updateData.find(({pk}) => channel.pk === pk)
     if(update)
       return {...channel, volume: update.volume}
     return channel
  })
}
```

Comment: what is some in `action.updateData.some(({pk}) => channel.pk === pk)` ?

Comment: Typo. I mean `find`

Comment: hey it worked. can you please explain how immutability affect DOM rendering

Comment: Redux consider state to be immutable. If you return the same object from reducer it assumes that nothing was changed. Hence no updates for subscribers (container components) and no updates for resulting DOM (why bother if the state is the same, right?)